# Get String input

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to get a String input from user.

I code it like:

```
String username= TEXT.getText();
String password = PASSWORD.getText();
```

Both are Strings, but it doesn't work. If I write it like:

```
String username= String.parseString(TEXT.getText());
String password= String.parseString(PASSWORD.getText());
```

Is that correct? The TEXT and PASSWORD here is a JTextField.

Comment: How exactly it didn't work? What happened when you tried?

Comment: when i click confirm, and it doesnt do anything. i tried to put showConfirmDialog for testing,  before this two codes and the confirmDialog is shown, but when i put it next to these codes, doesnt have any come out

Answer (score 2):

The [`getText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) method of any `JTextComponent` returns a `String`, so your first code snippet will suffice (you don't need another call to `toString`).

---

Relevant documentation:

- [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) (subclass of `JTextComponent`)
- [`JTextComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html)

Comment: The [`getText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As `TEXT` and `PASSWORD` are `JTextField` components in a Swing application, you can simply use:

```
String username = TEXT.getText();
String password = PASSWORD.getText();
```

as the return type for [getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) is already a `String`.

Note: [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) is used to accept passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as

```
String username= TEXT.getText().toString();

String password = PASSWORD.getText().toString();
```

No need of parsing.

Comment: getText() returns a string already, doesn't it ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29